# How do self-developing holographic plates work?

Tags: physical-chemistry, hologram

Litiholo started working on self-developing plates in mid-2004 and managed to achieve its goal and started selling these no-fuss self-developing hologram kits that produce pretty good results.
Unfortunately, I can't seem to find much information on how these plates were made to stop reacting to light after a set exposure time.

Answer (score 0):

Litiholo almost certainly uses photopolymer film attached to a glass or plastic plate. Typically photopolymer is exposed to the coherent reference and object beams first, then after a short delay is exposed to incoherent light.  The coherent beams establish a pattern of varying refractive index corresponding to the interference pattern formed by the object and reference beam.  The incoherent exposure consumes the unreacted photosensitive components in the photopolymer film.  After that, the film is no longer affected by further coherent or incoherent exposure.